# Why is my updateProfile functions is not worked even newUserData is correct but after if condition this is not worked?

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, form-data, cloudinary

I am unable to update profile i am checking error `req.body.avatar is undefined` but the code entered in this block `if(req.body.avatar)` why ? i am providing some code of it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLbr5.png) you can check here my updateProfile function i am try to chekcing by postman its work properly but with frontend this is not worked

```
exports.updateProfile = catchAsyncError(async(req,res,next) => {

    const newUserData = {};

    if (req.body.name) {
        newUserData.name = req.body.name;
    }
    
    if (req.body.email) {
        newUserData.email = req.body.email;
    }
    console.log(req.body.name,req.body.email,req.body.avatar)
    if (req.body.avatar !== undefined) {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
        const imageId = user.avatar.public_id;
        if(imageId){
            await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(imageId);
        }
        const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
            folder: "avatars",
            width: 150,
            crop: "scale",
        });
         newUserData.avatar = {
            public_id: myCloud.public_id,
            url: myCloud.secure_url,
        };
    }
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(req.user.id, newUserData, {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
    });
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you